# Get link to next page in post pagination (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I know about the link pages function (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_link_pages/)

to output a link to the next and previous part of paginated posts. But this always automatically does the output. Is there a variable I can access (or a function that returns) the link only, so I can continue coding with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, previous_post_link and next_post_link will allow this. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link and https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link.

EDIT: I see that's not exactly what you need. It looks like you can set arguments to wp_link_pages to define the output. For example, this should provide clear output and just the link:

```
wp_link_pages(array('before'=>'',
                    'after'=>'',
                    'link_before'=>'',
                    'link_after'=>'',
                    'nextpagelink'=>'',
                    'previouspagelink'=>'',
                    'echo'=>'0'));
```

The 'echo' argument appears to specify whether or not to print the html or just return it, so you may also be able to just set that to 0 and parse your output from there. Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome! I was able to set the output to a new variable, which seems to do the trick! Thank you Richard!